# TFS Reporting Server: Report that shows if work items were bounced from area path to area path

Tags: tfs, reporting

Management wants to be able track workitems that are bouncing between teams. Can we get a report and the number of times a workitem changes area path?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more elegant ways to accomplish this.

In TFS 2018, assuming you don't have issues directly querying the TFS database, you could run this query against the collection database:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.REV, A.AreaId, B.ID, B.REV, B.AREAID
    FROM vw_WorkItemCoreAll A
    JOIN vw_WorkItemCoreAll B
      ON B.ID = A.ID
     AND B.REV = A.REV-1
   WHERE A.ID = {workitemid}
     AND A.REV > 1
     AND A.AreaId <> B.AreaId
```

This will pull all work items that have a revision, align to the prior revision, and then pull out any where the area path has swapped.  You can add/remove filters or columns as you see fit.

Comment: Can we do the same thing but use the data warehouse instead?  I know MS doesn't recommend querying against the TFS database.

Comment: If the warehouse has a table with all the work item versions that includes the areaId or areaPath, it should be a similar query.